# Formula for $(A + vv^\top)^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1}$ and $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, inverse

Let $A \in {\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ and $v \in \Bbb R^n$. Is there a formula for $(A + vv^\top)^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1}$ and $v$, assuming that $A+vv^\top$ is actually invertible? I'd appreciate any references. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for the Sherman-Morrison formula. Bindel has a nice presentation here:

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f09/lec12.pdf

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. Gotta wait 5 minutes to accept, though.

Answer (score 1):

Carl Christian's answer is very nice, I will just give an alternative answer which may be less useful in this case but uses a general workhorse idea.

If $A$ and $A+vv^\top$ are assumed to be invertible, that means that $A^{-1}(A+vv^\top)=1+A^{-1}vv^\top$ is also invertible, which is equivalent to  $A^{-1}vv^\top$ having no eigenvalue equal to $-1$ (see comments below). Otherwise, since the corresponding eigenvector $w$ (which must be a scalar multiple of $A^{-1}v$) satisfies $\langle v,w\rangle A^{-1}v=-w$, one has that $\langle v,w\rangle\neq 0$ and therefore $\langle v,A^{-1}v\rangle=-1$. Not surprisingly, the condition for the validity of the rhs of the Sherman-Morrison formula is precisely that $\langle v,A^{-1}v\rangle\neq -1$. In particular, if $A$ is positive definite, both conditions above are satisfied.

Assume instead that $A^{-1}$ is invertible and that the operator norm of $A^{-1}vv^\top$ is less than one (the latter is a stronger hypothesis than the one discussed in the previous paragraph). In this case, you may use the Neumann series formula for the inverse of perturbations of identity, which converges in operator norm (by the way, this works with $A$ any bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space containing $v$ such that $A^{-1}$ is bounded and $\|A^{-1}vv^\top\|<1$): $$(A+vv^\top)^{-1} = (1+A^{-1}vv^\top)^{-1}A^{-1} = \left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}(-1)^k(A^{-1}vv^\top)^k\right)A^{-1}\ .$$

Comment: Unless, I am mistaken, then your second paragraph is a bit too strong. $I + vv^T$ is nonsingular, regardless of the norm of $vv^T$.

Comment: Your last assertion is true (as long as $v\neq 0$ and the dimension is greater than one) since $vv^\top$ is $\|v\|^2$ times a one-dimensional projection. However, the presence of a general $A^{-1}$ messes things up - take e.g. $A=A^{-1}=-1$, in this case $1+A^{-1}vv^\top=1-vv^\top$ is no longer invertible for arbitrary $v\neq 0$ (if $\|v\|=1$, then $v$ itself lies in the kernel of $1-vv^\top$). This also shows up in the Sherman-Morrison formula you quoted.

Comment: More generally, a necessary and sufficient condition for $1+A^{-1}vv^\top$ to be invertible is that $A^{-1}vv^\top$ has no eigenvalue equal to $-1$. This is indeed weaker than assuming the operator norm of $A^{-1}vv^\top$ to be less than one, by the spectral radius formula. I'll correct the hypothesis accordingly.